# What does (TextView) (Button) do?

Tags: java, android, objectinstantiation

This should be an easy question for someone who knows how it works.

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

What does the (Textview)/(Button) do, what is it?

Is it equivalent to

```
TextView myText = new TextView(findViewById(R.id.myText));
Button btn = new Button(findViewById(R.id.button));
```

Also, I might be mistaken, but this is in the java language not only in android?

Thanks

Note: Im not asking what a textview or a button is, im asking is this a type of instantiation, casting, etc.

Comment: TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText); is just intialization of textview. TextView myText = new TextView(activitycontext). you initialize your textview or button the one in closed braces `(TextView)` is casting to textview

Comment: So its an initialization and a cast in one?

Comment: yes it is initalizing a view ie textview or button

Comment: If you want, post a reply so I can accept this as an answer.

Comment: i just did answer for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing textview

```
     TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
     // the one in the braces is casting to textview
```

[public final View findViewById (int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29)

You can findViewById of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view.

If you want to do it programatically

```
     TextView myText = new TextView(ActivityName.this);
```

If you do as above you need to add it to the root view

If you have LinearLayout as root view

```
     setContenView(R.layout.mylayout);
     LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);   
     ll.addView(myText);
```

or

```
     setContentView(myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the (Type) like (Button) or (TextView) is called a cast. You can easily find any information about casts in any language on Google.

Comment: I know what casting is, I'm just not sure what putting it in that context actually does.

Comment: It's a cast, It just tells the system the view you're getting is a kind of what you're casting it. ;)

Comment: :) Thanks! Somerandomstufftofillthelengthrequirement

Answer (score 0):

Android is a platform, Java is the language used to write Android applications. So

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
```

is a cast (View -> TextView) in java and no, it isn't equivalent to use a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

[View.findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29)

Returns `View` type, this `View` type could be `TextView`, `Button` or something else. By doing cast (Which is what () means), you are telling runtime that returned `View` is of type whatever in those braces.

[TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) are subclasses of View type.